# checkbox checked value in asp.net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the following syntax to create a checkbox:

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("Monday", new { id = "Monday" })%>
                    <label for="Monday">
                        Monday</label>
```

in asp.net MVC2 view and when I try to get it in controller action like this:

```
string Monday = Request["Monday"];
```

Request["Monday"] has value "true,false". why so? How can I get current value (checked/unchecked of checkbox)

[EDITED]

```
 <fieldset>
                        <legend>Week days</legend>
                         <%: Html.CheckBox("Monday", new { id = "Monday" })%>
                        <label for="Monday">
                            Monday</label>
                            <%: Html.CheckBox("Tuesday", false, new { id = "Tuesday" })%>
                        <label for="Tuesday">
                            Tuesday</label>
                            <%: Html.CheckBox("Wednesday", false, new { id = "Wednesday" })%>
                        <label for="Wednesday">
                            Wednesday</label>
                            <%: Html.CheckBox("Thrusday", false, new { id = "Thrusday" })%>
                        <label for="Thrusday">
                            Thrusday</label>
                            <%: Html.CheckBox("Friday", false, new { id = "Friday" })%>
                        <label for="Friday">
                            Friday</label>
                            <%: Html.CheckBox("Saturday", false, new { id = "Saturday" })%>
                        <label for="Saturday">
                            Saturday</label>
                            <%: Html.CheckBox("Sunday", false, new { id = "Sunday" })%>
                        <label for="Sunday">
                            Sunday</label>
                     </fieldset>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, there is no much use in using the HtmlHelper to create your checkbox. It would simply by easier to make the code yourself:

```
 <input type="check" id="something" name="monday" checked="checked" />
```

Then you could access the value when you post like so:

```
 string rawValue = Request.Form["monday"];
```

Alternatively, you could make a view model and make a checkbox like so:

```
<% Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.MyBooleanProperty) %>
```

Additionally, when you use a helper like this, it actually generates the ID for you, so you dont need to assign the id of the value (aka, no `{ id = "monday" }` is required). In your situation, it sounds like you have assigned the same 'name` to one or more elements on your form, and thus the values will be concatenated together with a comma. I'd check to see if your page contains another element with the same name attribute.

Comment: Tejes: I saw that my page has no other control with same name. Actually I am creating checkboxes for weekdays and want to see what user selected by posting to controller action. I have updated the question and posted view code. Please suggest what should i do in thsi case ?

Comment: Switch to just a basic `<input />` tag instead of an Html helper and see if that fixes your problem.